# Change Apache rootdir to symlink, getting 403 Error

Tags: php, apache, symlink

I'm new to .php and servers and all this craziness (and StackOverflow) but I've downloaded Apache and I'm trying to symlink a PHP code folder to the Apache root directory. My Apache root was `var/www/html` and my PHP code folder is `Documents/PHPStuff`. I renamed `var/www/html` to `var/www/html2` and I made a symlink in `var/www/` called 'html' which links to `Documents/PHPStuff`, thinking if I renamed the symlink to the name Apache is looking for then it would work.

It doesn't.

When I try to access my test file in `Documents/PHPStuff` called 'helloworld2.php' in my browser with 'localhost/helloworld2.php' I get a 403 Forbidden Error.

I've been messing with permissions on the symlink and in the PHPStuff directory, changing them to 777 and stuff but it hasn't worked. I also changed my httpd.conf file by changing `FollowSymlinks None` to `FollowSymlinks All`. Nothing has worked yet so this was my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Try to don't touch your http.conf. Instead, edit files from conf.d path.

To grant access to your home paths, edit your /etc/http/conf.d/userdir.conf to activate user dir option, like:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
  #UserDir disabled
  UserDir public_html
</IfModule>

<Directory "/home/*/public_html">
  AllowOverride All
  Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
  Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>
```

then, restart your apache.

Now, you have to create a directory /home/$USER/public_html and create into it the symlink to your ~/PHPStuff, like

```
ln -s ~/PHPStuff ~/public_html/PHPStuff
```

You can move PHPStuff to ~/public_html/ instead create the symlink.

Ensure that your homedir have 711 permissions, public_html have 755 and the dirs and files inside PHPStuff are readable by everyone.

Finally, type into your web browser

```
http://localhost/~user ('user' is your system username)
```

and you will see your PHPStuff listed. You can type

```
http://localhost/~user/PHPStuff
```

to view the PHPStuff content directly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do all of that.

This is how I set up my symlinks.

When I install apache, it's web directory is located at /var/www/html which doesn't really need to be changed.

Then, I create a folder called public_html, you can call it PHPStuff, doesn't matter. What matters is that the folder is inside your home directory, so /home/your_username/PHPStuff

Then link that directory to /var/www/html

```
sudo ln -s ~/PHPStuff /var/www/html/$USER
```

You can then access ~/PHPStuff by going to your browser, and typing:

```
http://localhost/your_username
```

Which will give you access to ~/PHPStuff

After you do that, set proper permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~
```

Then make sure apache allows symlinks by going to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and editing this portion Directory "/var/www/html"

And make sure you have these:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

Restart apache and everything will work.

Comment: OK, I did all this so now in my var/www/html file I have a symlink my.username -> /home/my.username/publicHTML   , I recursively set permissions to 777, I changed Directory "/var/www/html" to AllowOverride All, and restarted Apache. In my var/www/html directory I have a helloworld.php file that I can still run in my browser with 'localhost/helloworld.php' but I can't run the helloworld2.php that I have in publicHTML with 'localhost/my.username/helloworld2.php' (which gives me a 403) or 'localhost/helloworld2.php' (which gives me a 404, didn't think it would work but worth a try).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure apache has access to the folder that the symlink is pointing to, try running:

> chmod a+x /home/your-username /home/your-username/Documents/PHPStuff